# SQL drop down selections in HTML

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and coding period. I've created a basic HTML page. In that page i want to create dropdown selections that produce outputs from my SQL database. MSSQL not MySQL.

EX: If I select a table or a column from dropdown one and then input a keyword for selection box 2. I want it to produce a table that shows the information in that table/column with that keyword.

If I select a medical name from dropdown and I want it to show only medical names that are equal to Diabetes. and then show me those rows from my database to a table. How would I show that in HTMl from connecting to the database, to creating the dropdown selection linked to the database, and then being able to select the criteria for what I want to be displayed. and then showing that in a table or list format.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is pretty broad and definitely more than can fit in a single StackOverflow answer. First you'll need to learn not just HTML but also SQL. Then you have to pick and learn a language to use on "server side". If you don't know what "server side" and "client side" are, learn that too. And only then, by putting it all together, can you get what you want.

Comment: Yea i figured. I've been looking into AJAX. I'm familiar with SQL and learning HTML. SQL queries im confident with. HTML and AJAX will take a little more time

Comment: AJAX means Javascript. It's just a fancy name for making HTTP requests from Javascript. But - that's another programming language. Although you can use Javascript on the server side too (via Node.js), so you could kill two birds with one stone here.

Answer (score 1):

OK, [Facu Carbonel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59903313/41360) is a bit... chaotic, so since this question (suprisingly) isn't closed yet, I'll write one myself and try to do better.

First of all - this is a VERY BROAD topic which I cannot answer directly. I could give a pile of code, but walking through it all would take pages of text and in the end you'd just have a solution for this one particular problem and could start from scratch with the next one.

So instead I'll take the same path that Factu Carbonel took and try to show some directions. I'll put keywords in **bold** that you can look up and research. They're all pieces of the puzzle. You don't need to understand each of them completely and thoroughly from the beginning, but be aware what they are and what they do, so that you can google finer details when you need them.

First of all, you need to understand the roles of the "server side" and "client side".

The client side is the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, what have you). When you type an address in the address bar (or click a link or whatever), what the browser does is it parses the whole thing and extracts the domain name. For example, the link to this question is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903087/sql-drop-down-selections-in-html?noredirect=1#comment105933697_59903087` and the **domain part** of that is `stackoverflow.com`. The rest of this long jibberish (it's called an "**URL**" by the way) is also relevant, but later.

With the domain in hand the browser then uses the **DNS system** to convert that pretty name into an **IP address**. Then it connects via network to the computer (aka "server") designated by that IP address and issues a **HTTP** request (HTTP, not HTML - don't mix these up, they're not the same thing).

HTTP, by the way, is the protocol that is used on the web to communicate between the server and the browser. It's like a language that they both understand, so that the browser can tell the server `hey, give me the page /questions/59903087/sql-drop-down-selections-in-html`. And the server then returns the HTML for that page.

This, by the way, is another important point to understand about HTTP. First the browser makes its request, and the server listens. Then the server returns its response, and the browser listens. And then the connection is closed. There's no chit-chat back and forth. The browser can do another request immediately after that, but it will be a new request.

Now, the browser is actually pretty limited in what it can do. Through these HTTP requests it gets from the server the **HTML** code, the **CSS** code and the **Javascript** code. It also can get pictures, videos and sound files. And then it can display them according to the HTML and CSS. And Javascript code runs inside the browser and can manipulate the HTML and CSS as needed, to respond to the user's actions. But that's all.

It might seem that the Javascript code that runs inside the browser is all powerful, but that is only an illusion as well. It's actually quite limited, and on purpose. In order to prevent bad webpages from doing bad things, the Javascript in each page is essentially limited to that page only.

Note a few things that it CANNOT do:

- It cannot connect to something that doesn't use HTTP. Like an SQL server.
- It can make HTTP requests, but only to the same domain as the page (you can get around this via CORS, but that's advanced stuff you don't need to worry about)
- It cannot access your hard drive (well, it can if the user explicitly selects a file, but that's it)
- It cannot affect other open browser tabs
- It cannot access anything in your computer outside the browser

This, by the way, is called "sandboxing" - like, the Javascript code in the browser is only allowed to play in its sandbox, which is the page in which it was loaded.

OK, so here we can see, that accessing your SQL server directly from HTML/CSS/Javascript is impossible.

Fortunately, we still need to talk about the other side of the equation - the web server which responded to the browser's requests and gave it the HTML to display.

It used to be, far back in the early days of the internet, that **web servers** only returned static files. Those days are long gone. Now we can make the webserver return -- whatever we want. We can write a program that inspects the incoming request from the browser, and then generates the HTML on the fly. Or Javascript. Or CSS. Or images. Or whatever. The good thing about the server side is - we have FULL CONTROL over it. There are no sandboxes, no limits, your program can do anything.

Of course, it can't affect anything directly in the browser - it can only respond to the browsers requests. So to make a useful application, you actually need to coordinate both sides. There's one program running in the browser and one program running on the web server. They talk through HTTP requests and together they accomplish what they need to do. The browser program makes sure to give the user a nice UI, and the server program talks to all the databases and whatnot.

Now, while in browser you're basically limited to just Javascript and the features the browser offers you, on the server side you can choose what web server software and what programming language you use. You can use the same Javascript, or you can go for something like PHP, Java (not the same as Javasctipt!), C#, Ruby, Python, and thousands of others. Each language is different and does things its own way, but at the end of the day what it will do is that it will receive the incoming requests from the browser and generate some sort of output that the browser expects.

So, I hope that this at least gives you some starting point and outlines where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is something that you need to know to do this, and that is the difference between a front-end and a back-end.
Html is a front-end technology, they are called like that because that's what is shown to the user and the back-end it's all mechanisms that run behind the hood.

The thing is, in your front-end you can't do things of back-end, like do querys from a database, manage sessions and that kind of thing.

For that you need a back-end running behind, like php, ruby, node.js or some technology like that.

From the html you can only call functions on the server using things like `<form  action="/log" method="POST">` this wold call the action `/log` that you should have already program on your back-end. Don't get confuse with this, there is plenty of ways to sending request to your back-end and this is just one way to do it.

For your specific case I recommend you to look up for ajax, to do the query on your database with no need of the browser to refresh after the query is made.

Some topics you need to know to understand this is:

-what's front-end and back-end and their differences.

-what is client-server architecture

-ajax

-http requests

-how to work with a back-end, doing querys to the database, making routes, etc.

-and for last, wile your server it's not open to the world with your own domain name, what is localhost and how to use it.

I hope that this clarify a bit this, that is no easy thing, but with a bit of research and practice you will accomplish!

Comment: Ive been looking at AJAX would that be the best route to go? Also i appreciate you answer i will research and look into those topics

Comment: Before I forget about it, there is something else you need to know, on html you can't do querys to your database, first of all because you can't program in html, there is JavaScript for that. And other thing to take in mind is CORSE policy wich prevent browser to access directly to things like file system. You need to have a back-end server running to do what you want!

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use AJAX to do the request the back-end to do the querys because the browser won't refresh while the request is done and it will show you the result in the DOM if you do everything right.

Comment: It's "CORS" not "CORSE", and most likely it's not relevant here.